# Which is the easiest way to identify the points which belong to a square?

Tags: calculus, notation

Let $x=(x_1, x_2)$ be a point in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the square "centered" at $x$ and identified by $x\pm T(1, 0)$, $x\pm T(0, 1)$ with $T>0$ (I hope that it is clear what I mean, otherwise I can draw a picture).

My question is: which is the easiest way to identify the points which belong to that square? I can't write them properly.

I was wondering if I can write them as the points $y=(y_1, y_2)$ satisfying $|y_1|\le T$ and $|y_2| \le T$, but actually I would like to have a more compact writing, not involving the specific component.

I hope someone could help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\|y-x\|_\infty\le T,$ where $\|z\|_\infty:=\max(|z_1|,|z_2|).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to say $|y_i-x_i|\leq T$ for $i\in\{1,2\}.$ There's no real way to escape componentwise notation, unless you happen to be familiar with the infinity norm $\lVert \vec v\rVert_\infty:=\max|v_i|,$ (where $\vec v$ is a finite dimensional vector). If you are, then all you need is $\lVert \vec y-\vec x\rVert_\infty\leq T.$

Comment: Cameron Buie, thank you for your answer. Does your answer hold true if I consider a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I consider the $n$-dimensional cube, isn't it?

Comment: It does, indeed! We just need to say "for $1\leq i\leq n,$" instead of "for $i\in\{1,2\}.$" It becomes much more challenging if the $n$-cube is rotated at all, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If $S$ is the set of the points of the square then $S=[x_1 -1,x_1 +1]\times[x_2-1,x_2+1] = \{(y_1,y_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2 |x_1 -1 \le y_1 \le x_1+1, x_2-1\le y_2\le x_2+1 \}$

Answer (score 2):

It's so easy you might have overlooked it. If $y := (y_1,y_2)$ is in the square, then $y_1 \in [x_1-1,x_1+1]$ and $y_2 \in [x_2-1,x_2+1]$.
so it holds iff
$$y_1-x_1 \in [-1,1]$$ and $$y_2-x_2 \in [-1,1]$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about a convex polygon is that it's the intersection of several half-planes. Each half-plane is an inequality of the form $a_i^T x \le b_i$, where $a_i$ is the normal vector of one of the sides of the polygon. The inequalities can then compactly written as a [vector inequality](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eee127/sp21/livebook/def_compwise_notation.html) and matrix-vector notation.

So, in particular, we can describe the square centered at $x$ as the set of points $y\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the following vector inequality holds:
$$
Ay \le Ax + T \mathbb{1}
$$
Where $\mathbb{1}\in\mathbb{R}^4$ denotes the vector of ones and the rows of the matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times2}$ are the normal vectors of each side of the square:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 \\\ -1 & 0 \\\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$
The length $T$ is the radius of the circle which inscribes the square.

By the way, with this notation, it's easy to generalize to a regular n-gon rotated by angle $\theta$. It's still the same vector inequality, you just use a different set of normal vectors, like this:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\\ \cos(\theta+2\pi/n) & \sin(\theta+2\pi/n) \\\ \cdots & \cdots \\\ \cos(\theta+2\pi(n-1)/n) & \sin(\theta+2\pi(n-1)/n)\end{bmatrix}$$
In the case of the square aligned with the major axes, $n=4$ and $\theta=0$.